# Create "simple" pagination for PHP, foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pagination

I'm pretty new with the "dynamics" programming, but  I really love it and now I need to improve my PHP web page.

Actually I have an PHP array, and I'm building "standard" html output inside a foreach cycle to build my page.

As you can see from the screenshot the actual result it's a page with a lot of `<div class="ui-content">`, there is a way, to simple create pagination where I'm able to show only six DIV entry per page, and create the menu to switch between page?

I think, the best solution is build something using advanced "dynamics" technics like AJAX call, but I'm totally new with this kind of programming.

Another possibilities is to use some pure java script at runtime to make the pagination, but I think this is not the best solution concerning the performance.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How many divs you have?

Comment: I don't know how many div my foreach loop will generate. Today are exactly six div and they should have to be displayed on a single page, tomorrow could be 14 and maybe in a year Potentially I will have a total of 1000 entry on my array ( actually I'm building this DIV inside a foreach loop built onto this PHP array

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: because you maby need to change you foreach

Comment: How you `foreach` is doing your divs? are you using sql? etc...

Comment: my foreach actually loop an array comes form API set of Limesurvey software. Actually I'm trying to avoid direct call to the MySQL database and create my page with pure LimeSurvey API call.

Maybe I can "split" my array in multiple array called array01, array02 and so on, then do a foreach only on one of the smaller array, and make a "menu" with a "post" call to the same page, and use that parameter to change the array show on the page.

I'll give a try to this approach.

Thanks to all for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

You Can try with simple Jquery Pagination, which is simple one to implement, but it loads the complete data and then paginate, in other approch like AJAX which request server each time you change the page.
Simple pagination jquery example easily available online. for example : 
http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/#page-2